# update query using jsp for updating dynamic data

Tags: sql, database, jsp, sql-update, prepared-statement

Connection is working properly. i am able to insert rows but 
getting exception (SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ) 
in updating the table , using following code.( BOX_ID is integer ,rest are varchar)

```
PreparedStatement p_statement2=connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE TOYS_TABLE SET NAME= ? VENDOR=? LABLE=? WHERE NAME=? AND BOX_ID=?");
p_statement2.setString(1, "abc1");
p_statement2.setString(2, "abc2");
p_statement2.setString(3, "abc3");
p_statement2.setString(4, "XYZ123");
p_statement2.setInt(5,11);

try
{

   p_statement2.executeUpdate();
   p_statement2.close();
}
catch(Exception kl)
{
   kl.toString();
   p_statement2.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
UPDATE TOYS_TABLE SET NAME= ? VENDOR=? LABLE=? WHERE NAME=? AND BOX_ID=?
```

to

```
UPDATE TOYS_TABLE SET NAME= ?, VENDOR=? , LABLE=?, WHERE NAME=? AND BOX_ID=?
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error on your `UPDATE` statement. You should delimited each column with a comma.

```
UPDATE TOYS_TABLE 
SET NAME=?, 
    VENDOR=?, 
    LABLE=?
WHERE NAME=? AND BOX_ID=?
```